# gunicorn: command not found with Docker and Dash Python

Tags: python, docker, pip, gunicorn, plotly-dash

I've recently developped a Dash Python Dashboard web app using Docker and I want to deploy it. (it's working perfectly in development).
Since Flask is not stable for deployment, I decided to use gunicorn instead.

I've added gunicorn in the requirements.txt.
I've replaced `python app.py` by `gunicorn app:server` in the initial script. And I've rebuilt the docker-compose to install the new image.

But I get the error `gunicorn: command not found`.
It seems that there is an issue with the path of gunicorn but I don't know how to solve it.

Here is the Dockerfile of the container named `container_api`:

```
FROM archlinux:latest

COPY api/requirements.txt ./

RUN pacman-db-upgrade \
&& pacman -Syyu --noconfirm \
&& pacman -S python --noconfirm \
&& pacman -S python-pip --noconfirm \
&& pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

WORKDIR /app

CMD chmod a+x entrypoint.sh && ./entrypoint.sh
```

Here is the entrypoint.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

gunicorn app:server
```

I specify that I have a shared volume named `app` between the host and the container. So entrypoint.sh is accessible by the container.
The log of the container is displaying:
`container_api | ./entrypoint.sh: line 3: gunicorn: command not found`

I also add the docker-compose file to see how the containers are built:

```
version: "3"
services:
  worker:
    build:
      dockerfile: ./worker/Dockerfile
    container_name: container_worker
    environment:
      - PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
    volumes:
      - ./api:/app/
      - ./worker:/app2/

  api:
    build:
      dockerfile: ./api/Dockerfile
    container_name: container_api
    volumes:
      - ./api:/app/
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    ports:
      - "${API_PORT}:8050"
    depends_on:
      - worker
```

What is weird is that when I was using Flask as development server, I had no problem using the packages installed via requirement.txt in my Dash app. It seems that using a package outside the Dash app (in the entrypoint script) is making problem. Do you know why?

I hope I was clear in my explanations. Thank you for your help,

Comment: Your `Dockerfile` should not work since you never added `entrypoint.sh` to the image.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to explain that I have a shared volume between my host and the container. The entrypoint is in the shared volume app. So no problem at this level. Moreover, the log of the container is saying: ```container_api  | ./entrypoint.sh: line 3: gunicorn: command not found```. Thank you

Comment: I created an image from your `Dockerfiler` with just `gunicorn` in `requirements.txt` and I can run it without troubles. Your problem seem to come from the volume and how you spawn the container.

Comment: Ok weird. I just edited my post and I added the docker-compose file. Do you have an idea from where it comes from? Don't you think it's an issue about the path of gunicorn?

Comment: Still can't reproduce. Please make sure that *you* can actually reproduce the issue with the information you gave us only.

Answer (score 0):

Ok it seems I discovered why I have this problem.

My development machine is a distant server and I'm developping on it via Vscode on my local machine with remote-ssh extension. I checked the Path and it's actually something weird with some vscode elements inside.

So I tried launching the docker without Vscode and it's working. I really don't know how to fix this issue but I will find out on vscode posts.

Thank you very much for your help